# PayTM gateway coming back to Callback URL without asking for payment

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, paytm

I am implementing PayTM Gateway on my ASP.NET MVC website. But it is not asking for payment instead after going to PayTM it redirects back to call back URL automatically.
This is the code generated by the controller:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
   <head>
      <title>Merchant Checkout Page</title>
   </head>
   <body>
      <center>
         <h1>Please do not refresh this page...</h1>
      </center>
      <form method='post' action='https://securegw.paytm.in/theia/processTransaction' name='f1'>
         <input type='hidden' name='MID' value='<MID>'>
         <input type='hidden' name='CHANNEL_ID' value='WEB'>
         <input type='hidden' name='WEBSITE' value='<WEBSITE>'>
         <input type='hidden' name='CALLBACK_URL' value='<callback>'>
         <input type='hidden' name='CUST_ID' value='1'>
         <input type='hidden' name='MOBILE_NO' value='7777777777'>
         <input type='hidden' name='EMAIL' value='abc@xyz.com'>
         <input type='hidden' name='ORDER_ID' value='31'>
         <input type='hidden' name='INDUSTRY_TYPE_ID' value='Retail'>
         <input type='hidden' name='TXN_AMOUNT' value='300.01'>
         <input type='hidden' name='CHECKSUMHASH' value='<checksum>'>
         <script type='text/javascript'>document.f1.submit();</script>
      </form>
   </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solved it. Redirecting to the wrong view in the action. And when redirected to the correct view it showed duplicate order id and invalid transaction amount. Corrected it and it worked. Hope this helps someone in the future.

Comment: can you share your paytm payment gatway code, I'm working but having problem in callback url. don't know how to create it, let's say xyz.com is domain then what could be the callback url?

Comment: @Deven This is a year old question. I am not working on the project anymore. But callback url can be any endpoint on your domain that accepts the data in PayTm response format. More details can be found in their documentation here; https://developer.paytm.com/docs/callback-and-webhook/